# Using PHP's array_reverse() on an array of arrays, getting odd behaviour. Why?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, [`array_reverse()`](http://php.net/array_reverse) is supposed to take an array, and return a copy of it with elements in reverse order, and it's always been working faithfully for me, up until today. I have an array of arrays, and I need to get them in reverse order, so I'd assumed array_reverse would do exactly what I needed, but it seems to be behaving oddly, and I can't figure out why.

My initial array (yes, I'm doing some HTML parsing):

```
Array(
    0 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 232
    ),
    1 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 593
    ),
    2 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 938
    ),
    3 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2627
    ),
    4 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2758
    ),
    5 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2794
    ),
)
```

running `array_reverse($arr)` on it, one would expect the returned array to be:

```
Array (
    0 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2794
    ),
    1 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2758
    ),
    2 => Array(
        0 => '</blockquote',
        1 => int 2627
    ),
    3 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 938
    ),
    4 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 593
    ),
    5 => Array(
        0 => '<blockquote',
        1 => int 232
    ),
)
```

However, it returns an unaltered array. Now, if I do `array_reverse($arr[0])`, then it reverses the entire array like I want.

I can think of no reason it would not be reversing the initial array, and why, when passing a specific key, it would reverse the entire array, rather than that one sub-array. Why would it be doing this?

**EDIT:** I walked away and came back, looked at it, and realized the main array had a single element which was the array I'd posted above. Just a good ol' ID-10-T error.

Comment: Can you create an example test case (e.g. on codepad) which shows the behaviour?

Comment: Works for me: http://codepad.org/68nDM11F

Comment: "yes, I'm doing some HTML parsing" Nice fending of the shit storm ;)

Comment: I walked away from it for a few minutes and came back, and realized I'm an idiot. I somehow completely missed seeing the extra array level at the beginning, so now it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, it returns an unaltered array.

[It should just work](http://codepad.org/68nDM11F).

> Now, if I do `array_reverse($arr[0])`, then it reverses the entire array like I want.

Are you sure you don't have an extra level in your array?? I'm pretty sure you have an extra level!

Comment: Yup! Just looking at it more closely (stepped away for a few minutes came back) and indeed I do! I don't know how I missed seeing this, and I feel like an idiot.